# OAuth gives me 401 error

Tags: ruby, oauth, twitter

I am trying to get the access key but I cannot make it work. ``request_token.get_access_token`is giving me`401 Unauthorized (OAuth::Unauthorized)`error. I copy the authorize_url into my browser, allow the application, I receive some kind of PIN from twitter but after hitting enter in my script I always get 401 error. I did some search and I found this helped`access_token = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])`but it is giving me`undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object (NameError)`

- the twitter application type is client
- the ruby script is like ( I was following [this tutorial](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/03/29/oauth-explained-and-what-it-is-good-for/) )
- I'd love to get out of this scrip access details. The best without using PIN.

.

```
gem 'oauth'
require 'oauth/consumer'

consumer_key = 'your key'
consumer_secret ='your secret'

consumer=OAuth::Consumer.new "consumer_key", 
                          "consumer_secret", 
                          {:site=>"http://twitter.com"}

request_token = consumer.get_request_token

puts request_token.token
puts request_token.secret
puts request_token.authorize_url
puts "Hit enter when you have completed authorization."
STDIN.gets

access_token = request_token.get_access_token
#access_token = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])

puts access_token.token
puts access_token.secret
puts
puts access_token.inspect
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem.
replace:

```
STDIN.gets
```

with:

```
pin = (gets.chomp).to_i
```

The to_i converts to integer which also acts to strip whitespace.
Then you need to specify the pin when trying to get the acess token. If you do not do this there is no proof that the user has allowed your application.

```
access_token = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => pin)

puts "Access Token  : " + access_token.token
puts "Access Secret : " + access_token.secret
```

Comment: when used your code I received `undefined local variable or method `oauth' for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: That was my mistake in the first example posted. I have re written my answer which makes the previuos comment irrelevant. 


The current answer should fix the original problem

Comment: great! works nicely. I can do that procedure of obtaining secret access details once and the use it later on.

Comment: As a side note, if someone is trying to follow this example for another app, like Yammer, which uses alphanumerical characters as pin, instead of converting to integer do
    pin = gets.chomp.strip